# Displaying items from a list onto the column in gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, listviewitem, gridviewcolumn

Im trying to display the name and path of a file in a listbox. For example, the name should come under Header FileName and path under FilePath. I do not want to bind  to any xmls, as i have a code to display the file name and size.Im new to this and im not sure how to go about this. Thanks!

Comment: @fatty everything ive seen so far has binding. Im not sure how to start also :(

Comment: Can you give us a snippet of code where you're trying to bind the data to the gridview and also the structure of the objects which are in the data that you are binding?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to help you without seeing any of your code or structure of the data you are trying to bind but I'll give it a shot.

Let's say you're trying to bind the names and paths of files in C:\MyFolder directory and your grid view has a name grd_MyGrid:

```
string[] myFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\MyFolder\\");

var files = from f in myFiles
                        select new{
                                    FileName =Path.GetFileName(f),
                                    FilePath = Path.GetPathRoot(f)
                                  };

grd_MyGrid.DataSource=files;
```

In order for this to work, you have to reference System.Linq.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To start you off, I will supply some code, but you really should read up on at least some of the basics when it comes to XAML and WPF for future development tasks.

If you can do without the ListBox, I would suggest using a `DataGrid` (in .Net 4.0 - or in the [WPF Toolkit on CodePlex](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)). The DataGrid is easier to use in situations where you want to display data in a grid or report.

To create a DataGrid in XAML, you can use the following code (in .net 4)

```
<DataGrid HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsToDisplay}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

This will create a simple `DataGrid` object for you to display on screen. Because `AutoGenerateColumns` has been set to true, your columns will be created for you automatically by the control.

You may also notice that I have set the `ItemsSource` property, this is the property that the DataGrid will get it's items from.

To define this in the Page code-behind file, you will be able to do something like this:

`public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsToDisplay { get; private set; }`

Notice how the name of the property in the code-behind matches the name of the property in the Binding on the DataGrid. This is how the View (page file) links to the ViewModel (code-behind)

To test it out, create a simple test class and populate the `ItemsToDisplay` collection with items.

**For example:**

*In my MainWindow.xaml.cs file*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ItemsToDisplay = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item>();

        ItemsToDisplay.Add(new Item("Homer", 45));
        ItemsToDisplay.Add(new Item("Marge", 42));
        ItemsToDisplay.Add(new Item("Bart", 10));
        ItemsToDisplay.Add(new Item("Lisa", 8));
        ItemsToDisplay.Add(new Item("Maggie", 2));
    }

    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsToDisplay { get; private set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public Item(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

*And in my MainWindow.xaml file:*

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsToDisplay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*Which looks like:*

[image]